# image uploading react input form: Cannot read property '0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to uploading images in react. I have my input where I am uploading the image:

```
<input className="your-upload-class" type="file" ref ="image"  onChange={this.fileSelectHandler}/> 
<button onClick={this.fileUploadHandler}>upload</button>
```

Here are my functions:

```
  fileSelectHandler = event => {
     console.log(event.target.files[0])
    }
  fileUploadHandler = event => {

    var files = event.target.files[0];

      S3.upload({
        files:files,
         path:"subfolder"
       },function(e,r){
         console.log(r);
        });
      }
```

When I choose an image my onChange functions shows my file information in the console like this: File(16862) {name:ect...

When I click the uplaod I get this error:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

I am not sure why I get that error when I upload but the information shows up when I choose an image. How do I get the file information in a variable so I can save it?

Also I am using Lepozepo/S3 and already have all my credentials set up in my config file but I think my problem has to do with how i am setting var files.

Comment: `var files = event.target.files[0]` in `fileUploadHandler` is wrong, the event is triggered in the button, so there is no file in here,

Comment: You need to store the files into temp variable or in state, then you can use that to upload the files.

Comment: Any luck with the provided answers

Answer (score 0):

I dont know react very well, but the logic is correct, declare a variable and assign file to the variable on input change event and then use that variable to upload

upload

```
 file;
  fileSelectHandler = event => {
     this.file = event.target.files[0])
    }
  fileUploadHandler = event => {

    var files = this.file;

      S3.upload({
        files:files,
         path:"subfolder"
       },function(e,r){
         console.log(r);
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your component, we use the `fileSelectHandler` to set the image in our state, we can then access this state from another handler within the same component, rather than try and get the same image again from the UI.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    image: null
  }
  fileSelectHandler = event => {
    this.setState = {
      image: event.target.files[0]
    }
  }
  fileUploadHandler = event => {
    const { image } = this.state

    S3.upload({
      files: image,
      path: "subfolder"
    }, function (e, r) {
      console.log(r);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // Stuff
  );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The probem in your approach is you are writing two different functions and considering **event** will be same for both , but its not.

fileSelectHandler function has event which contains file obj but not fileUploadHandler, because it is an onclick on a button.

So those two events in two functions are different.

So what you should do is:

```
 let file;
 fileSelectHandler = event => {
 file = event.target.files[0])
 }

 fileUploadHandler = event => {

  S3.upload({
    files:file,
     path:"subfolder"
   },function(e,r){
     console.log(r);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onSubmit={this.fileUploadHandler}>
  <input className="your-upload-class" type="file" ref="image" onChange={this.fileSelectHandler} /> 
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

The event.target is of the button, here we just submit the form and get the state information.

```
fileSelectHandler = event => {
  this.setState({ file: event.target.files[0] });
}

fileUploadHandler = event => {
  console.log(this.state.file);
}
```